# Remove Duplicates ... With NULLs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, null, duplicates

In MS SQL Server I am trying to remove duplicates from a table with nulls. Que the groans. Lots and lots of `NULL`s. The bottom line is I need to retain one copy of any duplicate record with or without `NULL`s. I basically want`NULL` to act like a normal record with a value of "`NULL`" for the duration of the operation, and then go back to being a real `NULL`. Is this possible? Is there a simpler solution?

`Table1` looks like:

```
UID        Data1    Data2   
1           A        NULL        
2           A        NULL       
3           B        abc     
4           B        abc       
5           C        NULL      
6           D        ghj
```

I want the command to throw away line 2 and 4 and keep the rest. (The SELECT is for testing.)

```
;SELECT UID, Data1, Data2
 FROM Table1 AS T
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM table1 AS T2
    WHERE 
      T2.Data1 = T.Data1
      AND T2.Data2 = T.Data2
      AND T2.UID >= T.UID
      )
    AND Data1 IS NOT NULL
```

NOTE: SELECT DISTINCT will not work as the duplicates have different Timestamps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Data1,Data2 ORDER BY UID)
    FROM table1
)
DELETE
--SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE RN > 1
```

**UPDATED FOLLOWING COMMENT**

Ok, if you are having issues to delete that amount of rows, then you *could* try creating a Look Up table with the Id's that you want to delete and then do a batch delete (you will have to test the batch row amount, though). This is an idea (assuming `UID` is a pk):

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Data1,Data2 ORDER BY UID)
    FROM table1
)
SELECT [UID]
INTO RowsToDelete
FROM CTE
WHERE RN > 1;

CREATE INDEX I_UID ON RowsToDelete([UID]);

WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
    DELETE TOP (10000)
    FROM table1 T
    INNER JOIN RowsToDelete L
          ON T.[UID] = L.[UID]
    IF @@ROWCOUNT < 10000 BREAK;
END
```

Comment: @user2366153 Ouch, sorry for melting your computer

Comment: Soo.. Update to the problem. I cannot run this without testing it as a SELECT first and it is throwing System.outofmemory after several minutes. Any way to do a sort first, then do this in "chunks" of about 10m records at a time?

Comment: @user2366153 Posted an idea for a batch delete. Let me know if it helps

Comment: Well it crashed again, (just figured out why: I changed the `DELETE` into a `SELECT` to test so it returned the same 1000 records over and over until it got bored.) BUT it did manage to output the new table `RowsToDelete` with ~30m records and after pouring over the first 1000 it is without-a-doubt the records I want to delete. I believe it finished the indexing as well. I am going to run it on the dev db with the correct syntax and see how it goes. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: @user2366153 Well, right, the `WHILE` will only finish if it was actually deleting records :-). Keep me posted about it

Answer (score 0):

Would `SELECT DISTINCT Data1, Data2 FROM Table1` not suffice?

Comment: That would work for selecting but if he/she is trying to remove duplicates from a table, no.

Comment: Sadly not.. the duplicates have different timestamps but are otherwise the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  ;WITH uTable AS (
    SELECT UID, Data1, Data2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Data1,Data2 ORDER BY UID DESC) as rownum
     FROM Table1 AS T)

    SELECT UID, Data1, Data2
    FROM uTable
    WHERE rownum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
declare @data TABLE (UID int, Data1 char(1), Data2 Char(3))

-- Your example data
INSERT INTO @data (UID, Data1, Data2)
VALUES (1,'A',NULL),(2,'A',NULL),(3,'B','abc'),(4,'B','abc'),(5,'C',NULL),(6,'D','ghj')

DELETE FROM @data WHERE UID in (
  SELECT UID FROM (
    SELECT UID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Data1,Data2 ORDER BY UID) as RowNo FROM @data
  ) d WHERE d.rowNo>1
)

SELECT UID, Data1, Data2 FROM @data
```